# What states base income tax on world wide income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I've seen several questions that state CA taxes worldwide income for anytime spent living in CA.  I'm curious what other states might do this (vs not taxing income which was earned wholly outside the state)?

Comment: Many state tax returns start from the Adjusted Gross Income reported on the Federal Form 1040, and thus will tax worldwide income because worldwide income is included in the Adjusted Gross Income reported on Federal Form 1040: the US taxes worldwide income.

Comment: Germany calculates your tax rate (whether you pay 20% or 40% or whatever) based on your world wide income, and applies that rate to your income in Germany. So someone making $50K in Germany and $50K in the USA pays the $100K percentage of $50K (more than someone making $50K in Germany and nothing else, exactly half of what someone making $100K in Germany would make).

Comment: The great state of Texas does not tax any income from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen several questions that state CA taxes worldwide income for
>   anytime spent living in CA.

Where did you see that? That's not true. CA taxes worldwide income of its **residents**. As almost any other State in the Union.

Comment: Well yes, I thought it would be obvious I was referring to CA residents.  It seem silly to suggest CA would be able to tax non-residents.  And I'm also looking for a list of states which do (or, if shorter, a list that don't).

Comment: "seem silly to suggest CA would be able to tax non-residents" Note that the US charges federal income tax to non-residents, on money earned outside the U.S.

Comment: Fortunately only US citizens who are non-residents.

Comment: @Andy there's a list of States with no income tax on wikipedia.

Comment: California probably also taxes employees who work in California but are not residents...

Comment: @Joe any state does. But only for income sourced to them.